# how to Get website Google position based on a keyword?

Tags: web-services, api

I searched Google search APIs and didn't find a way to get a website position rank based on a searched keyword and i thought its impossible.

But i found by luck this website "http://www.tools4google.com/search-google-position/keyword_tracking.php" which is doing the same as i want to do, so i just want to know the idea behind that, or its something illegal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It most likely is just scraping the results from all the pages Google gives you. That's why the maximum "number of positions" it lets you select is 1000.. because that's the maximum number Google will typically show you when you do a search in Google. Another thing that gives it away is that the time estimates they give on the page seems to grow linearly... if they used any sort of API provided by Google (or otherwise) it would ideally provide an indexed lookup based on the keywords.

What I mean by scraping is it uses a bot that goes through EVERY page result in Google (for a particular keyword*) .

Comment: And scraping is against Google's terms and conditions, right?

Comment: @Liam: [Yep.](http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS) `5.3 You agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services by any means other than through the interface that is provided by Google, unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a separate agreement with Google. You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means (including use of scripts or web crawlers)..`

Answer (score 1):

Try [rankog.com](http://www.rankog.com) it also does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it searches for the keyphrase and then ticks down the list until it hits your domain. Pretty intense but very simple through the API.

Comment: how simple through the API, couldn't find how